# Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log?

Tags: mysql, percona-server, xtradb-cluster

When I try to create a user story/issue in my my percona xtradb cluster I am getting below error. How to fix it? 
Error creating issue:

```
Could not create workflow instance: root cause: while inserting:
[GenericEntity:OSWorkflowEntry][id,10009][name,Agile Simplified
Workflow for Project FF][state,0] 
(SQL Exception while executing the following:INSERT INTO OS_WFENTRY (ID, 
NAME,  INITIALIZED, STATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
(Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary
log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a
storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to
row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ
UNCOMMITTED.))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your server is misconfigured, or (though somewhat less likely) your code is improperly setting the `binlog_format` system variable for the current session to `STATEMENT` (apparently these incorrect modes of operation are, appropriately, [more aggressively prevented in 5.6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster/+bug/1263991), so I assume you are using something earlier).

> # In order for Galera to work correctly binlog format should be `ROW`
>
> — http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.5/manual/bootstrap.html
>
> any binlog_format other than ROW was never supported (also well documented)
>
> — https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster/+bug/1263991

This should be the configuration in all of your nodes in my.cnf.  If your cluster has been running without this, the nodes may not be consistent, though it's hard to imagine it running like this at all, though there were [cirumstances in older releases](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster/+bug/1242867) that allowed the server to start with invalid configuration when it should not have done so.